# How to access same ledger from different chaincodes?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Suppose I have 2 peers(peer0 and peer1) and 2 chaincodes(1. full rights 2.only query).

I want peer0 to have full rights of invoking but peer1 to only have query available but installing and instantiating different chaincodes is creating different ledgers hence the query from peer1 is always empty.

So How can I access same ledger from different chaincodes?

Comment: did u find the solution

Comment: Nope, I didn't. I changed my approach So I don't need to access now.

Comment: what did you do? the scope was same to access the same ledger using two different chaincodes ?

Comment: I changed my scope. Started focusing on different problem statement. Do ping me if you find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of key-value data is actually channel/chaincode (meaning it is not scoped to the channel and each chaincode instance in a channel manages its own state).

So, if you want to "share" key/value state between chaincode, the only way to do this is to either always have one chaincode invoke another or you can extend this a bit and create a third chaincode which simply manages the get/put operations and have the other chaincodes always call it when dealing with the "shared" state.

[image: share ledger amoing chaincode]

Comment: You can access another chaincode from a chaincode with the [InvokeChaincode](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.InvokeChaincode) function.  I think some of the confusion around chaincodes & ledgers is due to [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peers/peers.html#multiple-ledgers) confusing documentation.